# A program to plot desired shapes!?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, graphing-functions, math-software

I am trying to generate some plots for certain function with certain properties. For example, $f$ is increasing from $a$ to $b$, with second derivative decreases exponentially, etc. (this is just a silly example). Please note that this is not about plotting a specific function but rather obtaining certain shapes.

Is there a program to help me generate plots without the need of a closed form of the function - just its properties?

The reason I ask this is because after proving some theorems with a general function $f(x)$ with certain properties, I want to show it graphically on my report.

Comment: There are infinite such functions, unless you make the properties so restrictive that you are essentially solving a differential equation. If your properties are as loose as the example you give then unless you provide a parametric closed form for the function you have in mind, no program will give you an answer.

Comment: I understand. That was not a good example on my part. I actually want to plot certain shape than a specific function.

Comment: I am not sure what "certain shape" means. Think about what you want and edit your question. Do you perhaps want a example of a function that would have the properties you describe?

Comment: Maybe a specific case of a general class of function. For example, $f(x)$ is linear, continuous, has positive derivative that approaches 0 at infinity, etc.